# Why can I treat a category that isn't small as if it were?

Tags: category-theory

I am working with a "combinatoric definition" of the zeroth and first homotopy groups for small categories.

Let $C$ be a small category, the definitions are the following:

1. The zeroth homotopy group is defined as the quotient set of the relation given by $X\sim X^\prime$ if and only if $Path_C(X, X^\prime)\neq \emptyset$. 
   Where $Path_C(X,X^\prime)$ is the set of all paths between $X$ and $X^\prime$ (it means the splice of an arbitrary finite set of arrows without notice if are pointing to the right or to the left, but the first object must be $X$ and the last one $X^\prime$).
2. Given an object $X\in C$, we define $\pi_1(C, X)=Path_C(X,X)/\sim$. Qhere the relation $\sim$ is the generated equivalence relation for this one:
   two paths of gap length one are elementary homotopic if one is obtained from the other replacing a morphism occurring as one side of a commutative triangle by the others two sides, pointing in the appropiate directions.

I am reading an article which works with the previous definitions in the category of n-extensions of $M$ by $N$, being $M$ and $N$ two modules. And at certain point it says:

*"The cautious reader will have noticed that the category $Ext_R^n(M, N)$ -this is his notation for the category of $n$-extensions- is not small, nor even equivalent to a small category. There are various ways to avoid this problem, depending on the underlying framework for set theory. We will ignore this point and treat $Ext^n_R(M, N)$ as if it were a small category."*

I don't even know why I could ignore it. The questions are: why can I ignore that fact? What are the ways to avoid that problem?

Comment: I don't understand what the first half of this question has to do with the second half. Anyway, one way to ignore this problem is to use the language of Grothendieck universes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe).

Comment: Presumable, OP needs the small category to use the definitions in the first part, but then the book tries to use the category in the second part. But it isn't clear. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought  the context maybe was relevant, because I don't know if it is a general issue or something that I can do because I'm working with these definitions. 

Could you be more specific about what should I do with Grothendieck universes for avoid this problem?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, what wrote Thomas Andrews is right, I have already edited the question. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. I claim that the category of $n$-extensions *is* equivalent to a small category. (Such categories are called *essentially small*; nearly all constructions for small categories can  be carried out for essentially small categories.) By splitting up long exact sequences into short ones, and induction, we may assume $n=1$. If $0 \to N \to E \to M \to 0$ is an object of $Ext^1(M,N)$, then there is a bijection $|E| \cong |M| \times |N|$ of the underlying sets. It follows that there is only a set of non-isomorphic modules $E$ which are extensions of $M$ by $N$, and for these there is just a set of possible maps $N \to E$, $E \to M$.

Comment: IIRC, the maps of $\mathrm{Ext}^n(M,N)$ are chain maps, ending with the identities on $M$ and $N$. $\mathrm{Ext}^2(0, 0)$, for example, is therefore isomorphic to the category of isomorphisms (with maps the commutative squares whose other sides need not be isomorphisms), and thus equivalent to the ambient category, which need not be essentially small.